# Xcode not autocompleting Parse methods

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

I'm using a lot of parse method/blocks like the one below.

```
[self.currentUser.profileImage getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:(nullable PFDataResultBlock(nullable )block]
```

Xcode used to autocomplete these blocks. Is this something that was broken with the last xcode updates? Is anyone having this problem and how did you fix it?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What version of Xcode?

Comment: @Droppy I'm using 6.3.2

Comment: There are mis-matched bracket in that statement; does correcting that make a difference?

Comment: no it does not - it's the output i get when i click enter ...which should auto complete the block but instead i get (nullable PFDataResultBlock(nullable )block] - wierd

Comment: Shouldn't it be `__nullable` anyway?